# How to install old version of Chromium?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, chromium, deb

Someone reported a bug in my open source project and he's using using Chrome 49 (I'm using version 55 of Chromium) so I want to install that old version but Chrome don't support 32bit versions so I need to install old Chromium.

How can I install it?

Comment: I know this is not very helpful to you, but from an external perspective, my answer would be *"Don't."* - Browsers are one of the most exposed and potentially vulnerable applications running on your system, it's a severe security sin not to keep them updated. You should try to encourage that someone to update their browser instead...

Answer (score 6):

Please just don't go on the website given in the former response.
This is a private website, no way of thinking it is safe, or not.
It's not because it's open source that you can download whatever you want.
Official repo give these instruction to proceed:

from https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

**Downloading old builds of Chrome / Chromium**

Let's say you want a build of Chrome 44 for debugging purposes. Google does not offer old builds as they do not have up-to-date security fixes.

However, you can get a build of Chromium 44.x which should mostly match the stable release. 
Here's how you find it:

- Look in http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/search/label/Stable%20updates for the last time "44." was mentioned.
- Loop up that version history ("44.0.2403.157") in the Position Lookup
  In this case it returns a base position of "330231". This is the commit of where the 44 release was branched, back in May 2015.*
- Open the continuous builds archive
  Click through on your platform (Linux/Mac/Win)
  Paste "330231" into the filter field at the top and wait for all the results to XHR in.
  Eventually I get a perfect hit: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/330231/ 
  Sometimes you may have to decrement the commit number until you find one.
  Download and run!
- As this build was made at 44 branch point, it does not have any commits merged in while in beta. 
  Typically that's OK, but if you need a true build of "44.0.2403.x" then you'll need to build Chromium from the 2403 branch. Some PortableApps/PortableChromium sites offer binaries like this, due to security concerns, the Chrome team does not recommend running them.

Comment: https://vikyd.github.io/download-chromium-history-version/

Comment: This is all very good, but when I unzip the archive I don't see any excutable file, just a load of project files with no readme / instuctions on how to build the project. E.g. this file https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F431801%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1479016198254000&alt=media